# how can i pass value from controller to datepicker?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am passing a value date from a controller 'Edit' to an input css datepicker however it is not displaying the value instead it displays mm/dd/yyyy. I've tried several options such as tag helper 'asp-for', 'viewbag' ,'viewdata' and 'tempdata' unfortunately doesn't change.

[image]

```html
//Controller

public IActionResult EditCedant(int CedantId)
        {
            if(CedantId == null || CedantId == 0)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var cedantsfromDb = _db.dbo_life.Find(CedantId);
           
            if(cedantsfromDb == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.DOB = cedantsfromDb.DateofBirth;
            
            return PartialView("_partialEditView", cedantsfromDb);
        }
        
        
[![enter image description here][1]][1]//View Input
   
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="datepicker1" date-provide="datepicker" value=@ViewBag.DOB/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put the date format in tag helper? Instead of passing the DateTime value in the ViewBag, try getting the value from the model:

`@Html.TextBox("my-input-date", Model.DateofBirth, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { type="date" })`

Comment: Hi @sycamore55 yes I did try.see below
<input type="date"  class="form-control border border-secondary rounded" asp-for=DateofBirth>

Comment: @Veck yeah I saw your input code, but that way doesn't work. Secondly, you need to put quotations for `asp-for="DateOfBirth"` and this should work properly. Also, I tried this tag helper that I provided for you and this is working fine for me? Both ways should work. What data type is the `DateOfBirth` property? Is it `DateTime`?

Comment: Appreciate your suggestion, will try this one. Btw the datatype is  a string. I was able to populate by passing the value to a javascript new Date() function however it returns a numeric no instead of date or string e.g 02/28/2022